# Is there a way to get data from a cursor object in Python at specific times?

Tags: python, sql

I'm using Python to extract data from a Microsoft SQL server using pymssql. The server stores data from some sensors every few seconds and I pull this by looping over the cursor with a simple list comprehension `(i for i in cursor)`. This returns data in this format: ('Date Time', sensor value) e.g.

`[('2021-12-01 07:00:00.000', -2.930029340293), ('2021-12-01 08:43:23.000', 413.1881316813), ('2021-12-01 09:04:33.000', 401.8150131502),]`

However, I only need values from the cursor every 6 hours (4x per day) rather than the 40000+ times I am getting it currently. I have tried to do this by including an if condition with the loop `"i for i in cursor if "07:00" or "19:00" in cursor"`  if I wanted data at 7am/7pm only. However, this always returns false for some reason even though I see the value in the output as shown above. Anyone got ideas on why or a better way to do this, e.g. modifying my Query?

Comment: (1) The string is never in the cursor but in the first item of the row from the cursor (in "i[0]"). (2)  "07:00" alone evaluates always as True, you must repeat the "in..." part